# Java Generics error: not applicable for the arguments <T>

Tags: java, generics

Sorry for another "Java generic method is not applicable" question. But no answer can solve my problem:

**Problem code:**

```
public final class Native<T> {

    private void test1(Ref ref, Integer key) {

    }

    final class Ref {
        private final Native factory;

        private Ref(Native factory) {
            this.factory = factory;
        }

        public void test2() {
           factory.test1(this, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

The method `test1(Native.Ref, Integer)` in the type Native is not applicable for the arguments `(Native<T>.Ref, int)`

If I remove the factory like this:

```
    public void test2() {
        test1(this, 1);
    }
```

Then it works, but I donnot know why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any difference between your working and not-working factory.

Comment: Why is `Native` generic when `T` is not used anywhere? Why is `Ref` an inner class with a reference to a `Native` instance? Why is the `Native` instance in `Ref` missing a type parameter?

Comment: BTW, your code compiles fine. The error message that you gave should not be coming for the current code.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, no factory in test2(), a typo, have modified it.

Comment: It's just a simple example, true problem is in jnr-ffi opensource code. I just extract the error part and change it for simple.

Comment: But it didn't work in my eclipse, eclipse version is 4.2.0, is it complier's problem?

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
private final Native factory;
private Ref(Native factory) {
```

to

```
private final Native<T> factory;
private Ref(Native<T> factory) {
```

You should never use a generic type as if it were not generic.